# Training model using BERT

Tags: nlp, data-science-model, bert, finetuning

I have generated dataset using chat gpt. Dataset has 9000 data recodes. It's 6 class sentiment analysis. classes are 0,1,2,3,4,5
I used 3000 recodes for training, 1200 recods for validation and testing.

This is the class counts

For training:

```
5: 622 ,3: 614 ,0: 593,4: 571,2: 604,1: 596
```

For Validation:

```
1: 221,5: 193,0: 193,4: 212,3: 182,2: 199
```

For Testing:

```
3: 204,2: 197,0: 214,4: 217,1: 183,5: 185
```

I trained this using BERT('bert-base-uncased') with 25 epochs. Learning rate 2e-5

This is the result.

[image]

Validation

```
Validation Accuracy: 0.5666666666666667
Validation Classification Report:
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.53      0.69      0.60       193
           1       0.54      0.50      0.52       221
           2       0.52      0.49      0.51       199
           3       0.54      0.50      0.52       182
           4       0.55      0.60      0.57       212
           5       0.77      0.63      0.69       193

    accuracy                           0.57      1200
   macro avg       0.58      0.57      0.57      1200
weighted avg       0.57      0.57      0.57      1200
```

Testing

```
Test Accuracy: 0.5658333333333333
Test Classification Report:
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.57      0.68      0.62       214
           1       0.49      0.56      0.52       183
           2       0.58      0.52      0.55       197
           3       0.59      0.49      0.53       204
           4       0.53      0.57      0.55       217
           5       0.68      0.58      0.62       185

    accuracy                           0.57      1200
   macro avg       0.57      0.56      0.57      1200
weighted avg       0.57      0.57      0.57      1200
```

I trained this with using different count of data. but graph shape is same with different accuracies. My questions are:

1. how to increase accuracy and what whould be the issue?
2. Is that a issue with some words in multiple classes (because i some words in many classes in this dataset)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overfitting A LOT.

This is usual when finetuning BERT on small datasets. I suggest you take a look at the [BERT article](https://browse.arxiv.org/pdf/1810.04805.pdf) to use it as a guidance for sensible hyperparameter values and finetuning strategies. For instance:

- They finetuned for 3 epochs.
- They ran several random restarts and selected the best model on the Dev set.
- At each random restart, they used the same pre-trained checkpoint as starting point but performed different finetuning (e.g. different learning rates from [5e-5, 4e-5, 3e-5, 2e-5]), data shuffling and classifier layer initialization (i.e. different random seeds).

Apart from that, check what optimizer you are using and how you are configuring it. In the original BERT article they used the Adam optimizer but disabling the bias compensation (aka BERTAdam), but this was counterproductive. Check [this answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/86557/14675) for advice on how to choose the optimizer and its hyperparameters.

Answer (score 0):

Your dataset is likely too small to support fine-tuning a whole bert model. The best approach in this case would be to use the pre-trained bert model to compute embeddings of your documents, then train a small MLP to predict classes from the bert embeddings.